# How to handle unplanned items in JIRA/Greenhopper

Tags: jira, scrum, jira-agile

I have setup Jira and Greenhopper and set up an initial sprint. I have mostly done scrum during my years via a whiteboard and face-to-face communication. I wonder how I should handle unplanned items using greenhopper? I don't just want to add a `New Card` and have it screw up the statistics. Would be nice to be able to get a figure of the ammount of unplanned work when the sprint is done. My initial guess was to add a `New Card` on the `Task Board` and tag it as an unplanned. But I don't seem to find any `unplanned` tag for a `Card`.

Comment: What types of metrics do you collect and are you planning on collecting with this? I'm asking because scrum is used so differently across various shops (metrics used for estimation vs. story points used for communication), so I think this would influence the answer (anywhere from "just accept that unplanned tasks happen, and budget for them in future sprints", to "add it as a subtask the story that it is related to, scheduling that subtask either in the current sprint, or a future one, and the burndown charts will show the points left metric as going up mid-sprint").

Comment: This is for a new team I will start using scrum with. I think we will do coarse estimation using story points and then fine grained one using hours or half days or something like that. Adding tasks mid sprint will bump up the burndown, this is correct. But I would like to be able to get a figure to show that 15sp was added midsprint as unplanned items and thus getting peoples eyes open and try to find the causes of this and fix it. Not so much for my own sake but for more non technical mamangement personal that are often the source for these unplanned items.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using Greenhopper for about 1 1/2 years.  It works pretty well and is invaluable to our team but isn't a substitute for post-its on the well for the daily stand-up.  Over the 1.5 years,  we've ended up collecting a lot of tasks, bugs, and other items in Jira that aren't immediate backlog items.  Managing them is the most difficult in Greenhopper.  These are the Unscheduled items.

I have these versions set up in Greenhopper:

Unscheduled:  this is a holding pen for a few hundred items that we may or may not ever get around to.  Some are ideas, some are bugs that we can't fix at the moment.

Unscrubbed bugs:  as we find new bugs that aren't related to the current sprint's work, they go in here.  Every week or so, we go through them and place them in one of the other versions.

Short Term Roadmap:  stuff we'll get to soon but not in this or the next sprint.

Sprint Planning:  this is the backlog we work from during planning.  It's the higher priority items.

v2.3 - Sprint 2 (or whatever version/sprint we are currently working):  This is the sprint backlog.

During the current sprint and before our sprint planning session, I organize the backlog and place the high priority items in Sprint Planning so we will get to them next.  After the meeting, we place the items we sign up todo into the v2.3 - Sprint 2 and them manage it on a daily basis.

Comment: do you know if there is a way to force create those releases across multiple projectS?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you say 'unplanned items' you are referring to critical 'hot fix' tasks that need to be done ASAP.  In my group we use a split team.  We have one team that commits to the sprint.  The Core Team.  They are the only resource we calculate on to determine the amount of work we can do in a sprint.  Another, much smaller team called the Firefighter Team is set aside to work on unplanned, critical items that, for example, might be needed in the next release.

We track these side-by-side.  The Core Team is NEVER permitted to work on a hotfix item.  However, the Firefighter Team is permitted to lend their skills as 'servants' to the Core Team if they do not have any critical items at the moment.  Our split on one project is typically 4Core/2Firefighter.  We rotate the Firefighter members each sprint, taking care not to remove someone from the next sprint that is in the middle of a big project spanning multiple sprints.  So far so good.  The only issue I have right now is tracking what amounts to parallel sprints in a meaningful way.  I'll tackle that when it becomes a real issue.

Comment: Sounds a bit like these firefighters might be ideal candidates for a "support/firefight/legacy" teak using Kanban?

Answer (score 0):

See my feature request to Atlassian and Vote for it.

```
"As a Product Owner, I want new PBIs quarantined from the Backlog until I rank them"
```

https://jira.atlassian.com/i#browse/GHS-11139